# Is the following matrix Diagonalizable or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

> Let $A\in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ and $A^2 =-1$. Determine if A is diagonalizable or not?

A $ n \times n$ matrix A is called diagonalizable if it either has n distinct eigenvalues and if the eigenvalues are not distinct then the eigenspace has dimension n.

So, I tried finding the eigen values first so, using $|A-\lambda I|=0$ to find $\lambda$ but I am not able to make any progress and I am unable to understand how should I use $A^2 = -1$ here.

Can you please help?

Comment: would you mind specifying what norm you are using to say $A^2=-1$?

Comment: One example the matrix $\{\{0,1\},\{-1,0\}\}$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: So I guess that by your definition $\begin{pmatrix} i &0&0&0 \\ 0&i&0&0\\ 0&0&-i&0\\ 0&0&0&-i\end{pmatrix}$ is not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you mean $A^2=-I$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix. Then $X^2+1$ splits with simple roots and annihilates $A$, hence $A$ is diagonalisable.

Comment: I got it that $X^2 + I$ splits with simple roots and annihilates A. But Which proposition you are using to deduce that it is diagonalizable?

Comment: $A$ is diagonalisable iff its minimal polynomial $\Pi$ splits with simple roots. So if there exists a polynomial $P$ which splits with simple roots and annihilates $A$, then $\Pi\mid P$ so $\Pi$ splits with simple roots, hence $A$ is diagonalisable.